# How to pick numbers between underlines using regex?

Tags: php, regex

I want to get only the value in bold, but I'm not getting.

349141_**194419414**_4828414_n.jpg

or

https:// hphotos-ash3.net/t1.0-9/1146_**54482593153**_1214114_n.jpg

Thank you already

Comment: Remove stuff on either sides of the _underline_.  Simple!

Comment: Swap for space both sides ?

Comment: Why don't you want to get `4828414` or `1214114`? They have underlines on both sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use preg_match with a capture group to get the result:

```
<?php
    $searchText = "349141_194419414_4828414_n.jpg";

    $result = preg_match("/_(\\d+)_/u", $searchText, $matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);
?>
```

output:

```
194419414
```

Answer (score 2):

(i'm not sure whether this one is good method or not but you can get whatever value you want to by this)

```
$r="349141_194419414_4828414_n";
print_r(explode('_',$r));
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => 349141 [1] => 194419414 [2] => 4828414 [3] => n )
```

---

```
$rr=explode('_',$r);
echo $rr[1];
```

output

```
194419414
```

Comment: I agree. Avoid regular expressions if you can.

Comment: $r="349141_194419414_4828414_n";
 print_r(explode('_',$r));
 echo $r[1]
 ?>

output

9

Comment: `print_r($r);` for all numbers

Comment: @Joe That would be `$n[1]`. You could also do `$n = explode('_',$r)[1]` and miss out a step.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
.+/\d+_(\d+)_\d+_n.jpg
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a regular expression answer.

```
$filename = '349141_194419414_4828414_n.jpg';

preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/', $filename, $matches);

echo $matches[0][1]; //194419414
```

Comment: That doesn't check whether there are underlines on both sides of the number.

Comment: @TimPietzcker it doesn't need to. Any non numeric character will break the pattern.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. It will pick `1` on the second example where it should pick `54482593153`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker @TimPietzcker I did overlook the second example, but getting around that would be as simple as getting the filename using `basename`